# iOS UICollectionView Detect if there are cells that aren't visible

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView, which is horizontally scrolling and set to being one row only. How would I be able to detect if there are cells that aren't currently visible on the screen; outside the bounds of the CollectionView's frame?

My idea is to show an arrow next to the UICollectionView if there are cells that aren't visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check with this instance method of `UICollectionView`:

```
NSArray *indexPaths = [self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems];
```

You could compare the first one with the first item in your data source, and the last one with the last item.

Answer (score 0):

That's easy enough to determine. Simply check if the data source for your collection contains more objects than the count of visible objects in the collection:

```
if (myDatasouceArray.count > myCollectionView.visibleCells.count) {
    // There are invisible cells
}
```